# Dynamics of burn down charts in Scrum

Tags: scrum, burndowncharts

I have a question about how dynamic the Y axis of a burn down chart in Scrum should be. We plot the chart in the beginning of a sprint having the total number of estimated story points on the Y axis, and the planned days on the X axis.

[image: Starting point]

Usually, during the sprint, we have a fair amount of:

- unplanned tasks / stories;
- tasks / stories that take longer than estimated (re-estimated by the person checking out the task);

Questions:

- should the story points of the unplanned tasks be plotted into the chart? if so, extend the y axis as well and redraw the expected curve? or just plot the points and have an actual curve with points maybe higher than the starting point?

[image: Some unplanned items, extend Y axis]

- should the re estimations be counted when plotting the chart, or just the initial estimations? same questions as for the first question...

[image: Some re-estimated items, plot the re-estimated effort instead of the initial one]

I would prefer to ignore the unplanned items and the re-estimations as they will show up in the actual focus factor calculation anyway. Is it wrong?

[image: Some unplanned or re-estimated items, ignore extra effort]

Comment: Maybe this should be community wiki since it is not really a dedicated question yielding a "valid" answer.

Comment: But there is a question though. Which of the three ways of updating the burn-down chart when there are unplanned items do you prefer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a burn UP chart.

http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/lee_richardson/forget_burndown_use_burnup_charts.html

Also, I would do everything in your power to stop the unplanned items.  They are typically very caustic.  If it's code debt cashing in, try to address it a little bit at a time in every sprint.  If it's a consistent amount of time every sprint, perhaps create a story at the start of the sprint for "unplanned tasks" or "production fixes" or something like that.

In the end, what really matters is that the burndown chart allows you to track progress (or lack thereof) toward the commitment.  So as long as you're achieving that, you're good to go. Which means, really any of these solutions would work - just pick one and go with it.

Answer (score 0):

We usually do option number 2 at work, adding the new story points to the actual line so that we "see" that the line goes up, reflecting new learnings and additions. But since opinions vary, I guess your team will have to agree on what suites them best, since these burndown charts are for the team to show progress throughout the sprint.

Answer (score 0):

What you count or not count should depend on what you are using your burndown for.

When I use a burndown it is most often to answer the question "Are we on track to completing our commitment of this sprint - or do we need to take external action?".

In that case, the thing that is most relevant to track is the "anticipated total amount of work left to finish commitment"; whether that amount was planned/unplanned or whether the amount was originally estimated to another amount is uninteresting in this context. It is still amount of work that need to be done - so it all counts.

So, count all remaining work. If the graph points towards the goal, keep working. If it points drastically different - take external actions (e g renegotiate sprint commitment w PO).

Now, you might be trying to answer another question (e g "how good are we at planning" or "are we having scope creep during sprint"), and in that case you would count in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

A burndown chart is useful for tracking progress towards the team's commitment.  In this case, it sounds like your team is struggling with two things that don't relate to the burndown chart:
1.  Unplanned work
2.  Poor estimates.

The key here is to focus on those problems.  No matter what you do with the burndown chart, if you're adding unplanned work and your estimates are poor... you'll never derive any value from the burndown chart.

I'd recommend a couple of things:
1.  Switch to tracking hours for Tasks... not points.  Hours are tangible for the team... they mean something.  Points are typically burned down at the release level.
2.  Try shortening the length of your sprints.  It's easier to achieve a smaller goal.
3.  Ensure that task estimates are no longer then 8 hours.  In fact, I'd shorten that to probably 4 hours.  Estimating tasks that take longer than a single day encourages the wrong behavior for the team.
4.  Ensure that you're spending enough time in Sprint Planning that that team can make a commitment.  An effective sprint planning meeeting is the first step towards an effective sprint.